# Solving minimization with smallest number of non-zero variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a function $f(x_i): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}_+$, and I know that $min f(x_i)=0$. I want to find its $argmin f(x_i)$ numerically. I am using `FindMinimum`, which works great.

Now I want to add a constraint, namely that the number of non-zero $x_i$ is as small as possible. I tried to add a [L1-regularisation term](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitions-on-l1-and-l2-regularisation-235f2db4c261) (sum of absolute of all weights) to the function, but it doesn't make variables zero, just makes them small

I could do the following:

1. Check with all variables whether I found f(x)=0
2. Make x_i=0 and find minimum again. If still zero, keep x_i=0, otherwise allow it for optimization.
3. Repreat (2) for all i

The code:

```
Loss=1-(Abs[x[5] x[7] + x[3] x[11] + x[1] x[15]] + Abs[x[6] x[10] + x[4] x[14] + x[2] x[18]])^2/(2 (Abs[x[5] x[7] + x[3] x[11] + x[1] x[15]]^2 + Abs[x[5] x[9] + x[3] x[13] + x[2] x[15]]^2 + Abs[x[6] x[7] + x[3] x[12] + x[1] x[16]]^2 + Abs[x[6] x[9] + x[3] x[14] + x[2] x[16]]^2 + Abs[x[5] x[8] + x[4] x[11] + x[1] x[17]]^2 + Abs[x[5] x[10] + x[4] x[13] + x[2] x[17]]^2 + Abs[x[6] x[8] + x[4] x[12] + x[1] x[18]]^2 + Abs[x[6] x[10] + x[4] x[14] + x[2] x[18]]^2));

vars = {};
For[ii = 1, ii <= 18, ii++,
  AppendTo[vars, x[ii]];
]
sol = FindMinimum[Loss, vars, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3];
If[sol[[1]] < 10^(-2),
  ZeroList = {};

  For[ii = 1, ii <= 18, ii++,
    CurrZeroList = Append[ZeroList, x[ii] -> 0];
    newLoss = Loss /. CurrZeroList;
    newsol = FindMinimum[newLoss, vars, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3];
    If[newsol[[1]] < 10^(-2),
        ZeroList = CurrZeroList;
        newgoodloss = newLoss;
        newgoodsol = newsol;
    ];
  ];
];
NecessaryVariables=vars /. ZeroList;
Print[NecessaryVariables]
```

It leads to the result that I can minimize the function with only $x_2,x_5,x_7,x_{18}$.

However, I have the impression that there should be much more efficient and elegant way. Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: This seems to be a difficult problem, indeed. The only observation that I can share is that the objective funtion is scale-independent. So it might help to fix a scaling, e.g. with an equality constraint of the form `vars.vars == 1`...